# Ember.js RC1 'model' hook on Route not called

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-router

It appears the `model` hook is not working as documented for RC1. The `model` hook is not being called when a `linkTo` is used instead of visiting the item directly by editing the url in the browser.

Given this example app: http://jsfiddle.net/wmarbut/QqDjY/

When visited directly at '/#/edit-item/3', the `model` hook is called, however when a `linkTo` call is used to direct the user to the same page, the `model` hook is not called.

Given the documentation here http://emberjs.com/guides/routing/specifying-a-routes-model/, I can't find anything to explain this. Is this a bug or am I doing it wrong?

**Edit**
I'm not using Ember Data nor do I plan to.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> It appears the model hook is not working as documented for RC1. The model hook is not being called when a linkTo is used instead of visiting the item directly by editing the url in the browser.

This is the exact way it's supposed to work. This is because the model is given via `linkTo`. When you write `{{linkTo posts post}}` the model is the 3rd argument. There is no need to call the model hook. The model hook is only executed when entering a state via the URL because it must look up a model.

In your fiddle you have `{{#linkTo editItem item.id}}{{item.name}}{{/linkTo}}`. You do no need to do that. You should have `{{#linkTo editItem item}}{{item.name}}{{/linkTo}}`. This will not solve the "problem" however. It will make the lookup automatic.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, this solves some of the problem, but still leaves me with an interesting looking URL `/#/edit-item/<Ember.Object:ember235>` instead of what I'd expect `/#/edit-item/3`. I'm investigating that presently.

Comment: I've created a gist here, that fixes the URL issue https://gist.github.com/grep-awesome/5078059. I'm going to accept your answer, but would love it if you would review this Gist and give your thoughts on the appropriateness of it as a solution.

Comment: You don't have to implement serialize for this use case.

Comment: @twinturbo - that's not a very useful response. Can you explain what you mean?

Comment: @Emerson you've probably figured this out already, but the default behavior for `serialize()` returns `model.id`, basically, you're writing the same impl that's already baked into the framework.